# What are Resizable iPhone and Resizable iPad on the new Simulator of xCode 6?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8, xcode6, simulator

What are Resizable iPhone and Resizable iPad on the new Simulator of xCode 6? How can I disable support of resizable modes on the application based on iOS8 SDK?

Comment: Resizable iPhone is an iPhone simulator that is resizable. It's due to the new devices. What do you mean disable support? iPhones aren't resizable, they just come in different sizes.

Comment: If I select iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus my application is displayed correctly. But it doesn't on Resizable iPhone. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

size classes is new feature in ios 8, resizable iphone and resizable ipad is brought to be able to test that feauture - build universal design app and be able to test resizing on the fly on one simulator.

Comment: But does it required to add support for Resizable iPhone for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: @Altaveron I suppose we are not able to add/remove support for resizable iphone/ipad. Look it gonna be boring work to test your universal design built with size classes on each model separately.

Comment: But should we add support for Resizable iPhone or not? And why?

Comment: @Altaveron  it's just instrument, as you said, there are no such iphone or ipad. But look, now the amount of devices increased and when ios 8 becomes lowest version, it would be better to use size classes and resizable iphone/ipad would save your time a lot, rather than switch between simulators.